# 66 inch tub in a 68 inch alcove?

Tags: bathroom, tile, framing, bathtub

Technically it's not an alcove, it's the back end of the bathroom, and I want to put a tub across that back wall. It's 68" across, and the closest tubs that I can find are 66". Seems like I should build out a little 2" projection of one wall, 32" wide ... or build out a little shoulder "wall" that projects out 2" and is 32" deep and 16" high and then tile horizontally across its top. The former seems more straightforward, but is there a standard/correct way to handle this; ways to make it look less kludgey? Either way it seems that tiling that 2" projection could get a little fiddly. Well, at least if I were going to do it, but I'm not; I'll hire a professional for tile installation.

Comment: Probably best to post the exact tub you plan on getting and a picture of the area.   Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Build the bump-out deep enough that you'd just paint the short wall, or fur out the entire wall. Avoid tiling it altogether. This is  pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Build a filler shelf or projection. Nicely done it can be storage for bath gel etc

Or you can use it for candles for added ambience...

And had to do a shelf like that for an 8" gap due to the size of the bathroom and the cast iron bath that needed to be retro-fitted. Some nice stained wood and tight edges with sealer and it is not a problem. Also had a tiny slope from back to the front edge so that any splashed water does not sit at the back edge.